# AngularJS nested ng-repeat of classes

Tags: c#, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have a repeater that shows grades of a class. And in my repeater i have a filter that makes each grade show only once. And now i want to show all the classes that are in that specific grade. for example if i have 2 classes class A and Class B in grade 1. I want to show that that grade has 2 classes. A and B
how do i do that?

as of now the code shows only 1 class in that specific grade and not both of them. how do i make it only show the classes that are in that grade?

EmployeeCtrl.info  is an array containing

```html
0: Object$$hashKey: "object:6"Grade: 1Id: "AA6C05F9-98DF-4A8D-B055-10DB07557F0D"Name: "1C"TeacherId: "1E51E989-8ED5-4988-B929-4FBCD8A7977D"__proto__: Object1: Object$$hashKey: "object:10"Grade: 1Id: "C07D54D9-01B0-4CC8-A8CC-0FDD47EAFE5C"Name: "1B"TeacherId: "1E51E989-8ED5-4988-B929-4FBCD8A7977D"__proto__: Object2: Object$$hashKey: "object:7"Grade: 2Id: "15218673-874B-41C1-9910-AD4F185F5730"Name: "2C"TeacherId: "1E51E989-8ED5-4988-B929-4FBCD8A7977D"__proto__: Object3: Object$$hashKey: "object:11"Grade: 2Id: "4711EEEE-4B56-4FD8-9A15-648CE00090A3"Name: "2A"TeacherId: "1E51E989-8ED5-4988-B929-4FBCD8A7977D"
```

html / repeater code :

```html
<div class="col-md-4 gradeSelect" ng-click="EmployeeCtrl.ClassClick()" ng-repeat="g in EmployeeCtrl.info | unique: 'Grade'">
            <h1>Årskurs {{g.Grade}} </h1>

           Klass {{g.Name}}</a>
           
        </div>
```

Filter code :

```html
.filter('unique', function () {
    return function (collection, keyname) {
        var output = [],
            keys = [];

        angular.forEach(collection, function (item) {
            var key = item[keyname];
            if (keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                keys.push(key);
                output.push(item);
            }
        });

        return output;
    };
})
```

and if i add another repeater for the name of the grade it shows all of the classes in all the grades.

changed html/ repeater code :

```html
  <div class="col-md-4 gradeSelect" ng-click="EmployeeCtrl.ClassClick()" ng-repeat="g in EmployeeCtrl.info | unique: 'Grade'">
            <h1>Årskurs {{g.Grade}} </h1>

           <a ng-repeat="g in EmployeeCtrl.info"> {{g.Name}}</a>
           
        </div>
```

how do i make it only show the names of the classes in the same grade?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, second time you r not actually using the filtered results

```html
  <div class="col-md-4 gradeSelect" ng-click="EmployeeCtrl.ClassClick()" ng-repeat="g in filteredGrades=(EmployeeCtrl.info | unique: 'Grade')">
            <h1>Årskurs {{g.Grade}} </h1>

           <a ng-repeat="g in filteredGrades"> {{g.Name}}</a>
           
        </div>
```

Comment: didnt work . now it just gives out 1 class of each grade, in both grades. since u used the filter i had to take away the doubles of grades. thx for the effort though.

Comment: can u please provide a data snippet??

Comment: what do u mean? the array that the function brings back from the database?

Comment: ok i resolved it myself.  this worked with angularJS own filter .....<div class="col-md-4 gradeSelect" ng-click="EmployeeCtrl.ClassClick()" ng-repeat="g in EmployeeCtrl.info | unique: 'Grade'">
            <h1>Årskurs {{g.Grade}} </h1>

            <a ng-repeat="c in EmployeeCtrl.info | filter:{Grade:g.Grade}"> {{c.Name}}</a>